# Have a button with c:forEach, which will redirect to a specific page

Tags: java, sql, jsp, ctags

so I'm reading out values from a table with c:forEach but i need to link them with a href which will redirect the user to that specific page :(

```
<sql:query dataSource="${vle}" var="courses">
                    SELECT course_name FROM courses
                    </sql:query>
                    <c:forEach var="courses" items="${courses.rows}">

                        <a href=".jsp">${courses.course_name}</a>
                        <br/>

                    </c:forEach>
```

here's the output

[image]

Comment: what i want is when the user clicks the link to redirect him to that specific web page, the jsp page will have the same names, but i dont know how to set the href with each forEach output, thanks

Comment: <a href="courseDetails.jsp?course=${courses.course_name}">link text</a>

Answer (score 0):

If you use ordinary servlets you can do something like this

```
<a href="courses?course_name=${courses.course_name}">${courses.course_name}</a>
```

Also you need to have a servlet mapped with "courses" URL. It will read attribute "course name" from GET request and depending on its value redirect user to the page he have chosen.